# Lookup CSS dropdown-alignment implementation in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-combobox, lookup-field

I'm currently having some issues with the lookup implementation that is being used within a lightning-datatable implementation.

[image]

The lookup bar is being cutoff, and instead pushes the entire table segment down and makes it scrollable within the container causing this.

[image]

Which would be fine except for the fact that it's not immediately obvious it's happening unless the container itself is being scrolled down.

On the other hand, using the lightning-combobox with the `dropdown-alignment='auto'` gives me what I wanted. [image]

I've been working off of the Lightning Design Systems to create a lookup class - https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/, so I'm not sure how to properly implement this so that the dropdown from the lookup aligns properly

Comment: When you say alignment, do you mean that your dropdown is being hidden behind the edge of the datatable, but the salesofrce lightning-combobox is being displayed over the top of the edge of the container?

Comment: Yeah - the combobox has the dropdown-alignment that allows it to escape the datatable, but I'm not sure how to implement that for the lookup

Answer (score -1):

Since I wasn't able to find any build in salesforce method to do this, I resolved this by changing the listbox to a fixed position and calculating the position of the input within the window and set the style with that.

It's a bit hacky, but this is what I did to set the style

```
    setDropdownStyle() {
        let style = "position:fixed; z-index:10000;";
        if (this.template.querySelector("[data-id='lookup-combobox']")) {
            let boundingBox = this.template.querySelector("[data-id='lookup-combobox']").getBoundingClientRect();
            style += `top: ${boundingBox.top+30}px; left: 150px`; 
        }
        this.template.querySelector("[data-id='listbox']").style = style;
    }
```

Comment: Great that you found a workaround, kudos! Adding relevant code to the answer would be super helpful for future readers. Thanks!